# Wordpress on EC2 instance can't connect to the RDS

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, rds, vpc

The log files in RDS instance gave me this error. The RDS and the EC2 instance are on the same subnet, security group looks fine to me as I have assigned 0.0.0.0/0 on the mysql port. The private IP is not getting resolved. Please help me with this issue, here is the image of the error:
[image]

Comment: I just realized that the RDS dashboard says supported platform as VPC and not EC2-VPC. Does that has to do anything with the issue I'm facing?

Answer (score 0):

It was the SELinux problem. Got it fixed. Thanks.